# How is this program running in debug mode?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am confused about something I saw today

In a Linux terminal the next commands were given:

```
g++ hw.cpp 
./a.out
./a.out debug
```

The second command executes the program and outputs "Hello, World"

The third command seems to run the program in a debug mode and makes the same program output "sending output to terminal" "Hello, World"

I did not see the source code

How can I make my own program only output certain lines in debug mode?

Comment: I don't have the source code, if I did I would not be asking

Comment: The program in the third case (not the second, please try at least a little to be accurate) is looking at the commandlime parameters of the main() function, and doing something different if there is one which is the string "debug".

Comment: Sorry fixed, I will have a look at main() parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source is in `hw.cpp`, which obviously is using some kind of argument parsing to look for 'debug'.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "debug") == 0)
    printf("Hello World\n");

  return 0;
}
```

If you would like to do argument parsing more involved then this I suggest you look to [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)

Comment: Thank you, I don't have the source code for hw.cpp but I will let you know if I can get this to work

Comment: Again what is with the down votes? This exactly answers the question!

Comment: I know right, it was an honest question from an honest newbie, there is no need for destructive criticism here

Comment: What? This doesn't even compile, let alone is close to a useful C++ answer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Oh, I am so sorry that there was a single character error in there. Down votes are fine, but down votes without constructive criticism is idiotic. How the hell is the author supposed to know why they got down voted? The question was broad, the code presented was a simple example, get over it.

Comment: *"How the hell is the author supposed to know why they got down voted?"* Trying if the downvoted answer actually works tends to be a good first step. Also, throwing answers using stuff that's been deprecated for about 20 years now at newbies is harmful, please read a C++ book from this decade before posting more C++ answers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen C, which C++ is based on, is not deprecated in any way shape or form. I agree that best practice should be observed, and you likely correct in stating that it should be using std::string, etc... my point still stands. Unless you are blind, SO informs you when you downvote you should post a comment informing the poster why you downvoted to help them too! Just downvoting without saying why is just stupid, you can't expect everyone to know everything.

Comment: *"C, which C++ is based on, is not deprecated in any way shape or form."* That's not a useful argument. Don't post C answers to C++ questions. *"Just downvoting without saying why is just stupid, you can't expect everyone to know everything."* I was hoping that someone with your experience on this site takes a step back and reevaluates their answer when they get negative feedback via votes. Apparently, that was too optimistic.